# Как добавить модуль YAML в OpenServer5.3?

Tags: dll, openserver, yaml

ужно установить модуль yaml в OpenServer для корректного отображения сайта.
Скачал файл yaml.dll по ссылке: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ya...
закинул по пути: D:\open_server_5_3_0_basic\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP_7.0-x64 ,
в php.ini добавил два файла потому , что не знаю какой именно нужно добавить(по отдельности добавлял,тоже не работает) extension=php_yaml.dll и extension=yaml.dll.
Может кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой и поможет решить.
Спасибо:)

Ошибка при отображении сайта:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file()

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался:)
Чтобы установить YAML  в моем случае нужно было скачать https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/yaml/2.0.4/php_yaml-2.0.4-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip
 А в конфигурационном файле PHP _7.0_x64 подключить две библиотеки:
 extension=php_yaml.dll
extension=yaml.dll